# solve (limit) integral expression into numerical values in Matlab

Tags: function, matlab, symbolic-integration

My expression (after final evaluation) turned out to be a very complicated integral expression. It involves inverse of a function, within function.

I am using symbolic function to solve this. Unfortunately i could not get the answer in terms of expression that I need. Can someone guide me with that ?

Following is my code;

```
    dn=2;
    pfa = .1;
    dref = 1;

    syms x z
    lo_x_lim = erfinv(pfa-1)*sqrt(2);
    hi_x_lim = inf;

    lo_z_lim = 0
    hi_z_lim = dn

    %% Expression

    Q(x,z) = .5 +.5*erf(x/sqrt(2))
    Qinv_ = erfinv(Q - pfa/2) %Note that this need to be changed
    f_step_2 = (Qinv_ - x)/(1-z/dref)
    f_step_3 = Q(f_step_2,0)

    g(x,z) = 2*z/dn^2
    h(x,z) = exp(-x^2/2)

    %combining three equations to form one
    fin = f_step_3*g*h

    % Doing double integral wrt x and z in two steps
    %integrate wrt x
    int_x = int(fin,x,-0.2,hi_x_lim)

    %integrate wrt z

    int_z = int(int_x,z,lo_z_lim,hi_z_lim)
```

Following is the final answer that I am getting. (Note that I need it in terms floating-point format)

```
int_z =

int(int((z*exp(-x^2/2)*(erf((2^(1/2)*(x - erfinv(erf((2^(1/2)*x)/2)/2 + 9/20)))/(2*(z - 1)))/2 + 1/2))/2, x, -.2, Inf), z, 0, 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symbolic computations typically strive to maintain as exact an answer as possible.  For a definite integral, this means the engine needs to find the anti-derivative of the integrand and then evaluate it at the integration bounds.  If it cannot find the anti-derivative, the engine may throw an error/warning or, in the case of the Matlab Symbolic Toolbox and some other engines,  ["it just returns `int(f)`"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/integration.html).  However, you can force `int` to return a numerical approximation to the definite integral using `double`.  Changing the final line to

```
int_z = double(int(int_x,z,lo_z_lim,hi_z_lim));
```

will produce a numerical approximation.  However, due to the complexities of the integrand, it takes a fairly long time.  As I repeatedly like to soapbox about, if you're in search of a number, you probably want to use numbers at the end.  Consider the direct numerical approximation using `integral2`:

```
fin_num   = matlabFunction(fin,'Vars',[x,z]);
int_z_num = integral2(fin_num,-0.2,hi_x_lim,lo_z_lim,hi_z_lim);
```

Running the modified code outputs

```
int_z =
    0.6957
Elapsed time is 841.910756 seconds.
int_z_num =
    0.6957
Elapsed time is 0.219571 seconds.
```

Comment: Thanks. It helps. Also for me it did not take much time. I am using windows 7 with 8G RAM. May be this is the reason for your slow processing. But loads of thanks

Comment: @Sjaffry Glad it works. Out of curiosity, what are the run times of the symbolic and numeric calculations?

Comment: I have not calculated it. Since it is almost none. Almost just after click of a mouse button !!!